# MySQL Stored Procedure In Query

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I want to make a MySQL Stored Procedure

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `SECTOR_INDUSTRY_SP` $$
CREATE PROCEDURE `SECTOR_INDUSTRY_SP`(IN RINSERIES TEXT, IN COMMUNITYIDS TEXT)
    READS SQL DATA
BEGIN
SELECT *
from PROFESSIONAL_IDENTITY_MERGED p , std_company_detail s
where (p.pim_company_id = s.cid) AND p.pim_community_id IN  ('+'+COMMUNITYIDS+'+')
AND p.pim_rin IN  ('+'+RINSERIES+'+');

END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

As you can see I have two arguments to call this procedure RINSERIES which would be text format like '12312,1234,1239' similarly COMMUNITYIDS is like '2,5,8' but When I would pass, it is interpreting like

```
SELECT *
    from PROFESSIONAL_IDENTITY_MERGED p , std_company_detail s
    where (p.pim_company_id = s.cid) AND p.pim_community_id IN  ('12312,1234,1239')
    AND p.pim_rin IN  ('2,5,8');
```

But I want this query to look like following

```
SELECT *
        from PROFESSIONAL_IDENTITY_MERGED p , std_company_detail s
        where (p.pim_company_id = s.cid) AND p.pim_community_id IN  (12312,1234,1239)
        AND p.pim_rin IN  (2,5,8);
```

How can I do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `SECTOR_INDUSTRY_SP` $$
CREATE PROCEDURE `SECTOR_INDUSTRY_SP`(IN RINSERIES TEXT, IN COMMUNITYIDS TEXT)
    READS SQL DATA
BEGIN

SET @s = CONCAT("SELECT *
from PROFESSIONAL_IDENTITY_MERGED p , std_company_detail s
where (p.pim_company_id = s.cid) AND p.pim_community_id IN  (", COMMUNITYIDS, ")
AND p.pim_rin IN  (",RINSERIES,")");

PREPARE stmt FROM @s;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Can it be used for the declaring a cursor ?